# Hibernate: Map an association to several Map fields in an entity class

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

Suppose I have an `Author` entity that has a `ManyToMany` relationship with a `Book` entity:

```java
@Entity
public class Author {
 
    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(
        name="AuthorBookGroup",
        joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="fk_author", referencedColumnName="id")},
        inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="fk_group", referencedColumnName="id")})
    @MapKey(name = "title")
    private Map<String, Book> books = new HashMap<String, Book>();
 
    ...
}
```

I can represent it as a `Map` in which the keys are the titles of the books.

However I'd also like to access books by their years of publication. Is it possible to have both maps in an `Author` entity?

```java
private Map<String, Book> booksByTitle = new HashMap<String, Book>();
private Map<Integer, Book> booksByYear = new HashMap<Integer, Book>();
```

If possible, would it be a good practice, or would I be better off using a `DTO` projection?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible because there could be many books the same year, it could be Map<Integer, Set> but things start to get weird.

It also doesn't seem a good idea, since changes in one of the relations could lead to unconsistent internal representation.

I would have the list of books, and just perform the query. You could have post construct that create indices if you need them, but that would be an optimization. I would just resolve the queries with criteria.